# Python- urllib.urlencode: parse dictionary items into string

Tags: python, urllib, ordereddictionary

I need to encode dictionary item like this

```
data = OrderedDict([('mID', ['54a309ae1c61be23aba0da54', '54a309ae1c61be23aba0da63'])])
```

into a string formatted like this

```
mID=[54a309ae1c61be23aba0da54,54a309ae1c61be23aba0da63]
```

When I use `url_values = urllib.urlencode(data)`
I get `mID=%5B%2754a309ae1c61be23aba0da54%27%2C+%2754a309ae1c61be23aba0da63%27%5D`

What could I do?

Comment: For the part inside the brackets, see `str.join()`, for the whole thing `str.format()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be:

```
"{}=[{}]".format("mID",",".join(data["mID"]))
```

Comment: Please read about sting formatting and join in python @A_Matar

Answer (score 1):

With [***urllib.parse***](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html) module for Python v3.x:

```
import collections
from urllib import parse

data = collections.OrderedDict([('mID', ['54a309ae1c61be23aba0da54', '54a309ae1c61be23aba0da63'])])
urlenc_str = parse.unquote_plus(parse.urlencode(data))
urlenc_str = urlenc_str.replace("'", '').replace(' ', '')

print(urlenc_str)
```

The output:

```
mID=[54a309ae1c61be23aba0da54,54a309ae1c61be23aba0da63]
```

Checking type:

```
print(type(urlenc_str))    #  <class 'str'>
```

Comment: I am using python2 and when trying to import parse it gives me `ImportError: cannot import name parse`

Comment: @A_Matar, I'm afraid it's for Python 3.x